# Create Proxy Server in react application

Tags: node.js, reactjs, azure, express, proxy-server

I just want to know how we can set cookies/get azure token on proxy server side for security purpose.

As the api key and other secret keys are not secure on front end side like in .env file.

I just want to use a proxy server with my react application so that security keys will not visible.
My main issue is I don't know how I can use azure token/credential : include(how to set that cookie) on api function header.

Appreciate help.